# What makes this deconstruct never be called

Tags: c++

I am trying to understand the memory leak.
I don't understand why below MyInt deconstruct in main is never called and a memory leak happens.

```
  class MyInt
    {
        int *_p; 
    public:
        MyInt(int *p = NULL) { _p = p; }
        ~MyInt() 
        { 
            delete _p; 
        }
        int &operator*() { return *_p; }
    };

int main()
{
    double t[] = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0};
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        MyInt *en = new MyInt(new int(i));
        std::cout << **en << "/" << t[i] << " = " << **en / t[i] << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For every `new` you write, you need a paired `delete`, somewhere.  You did this properly for the MyInt ctor/dtor _p member, but the client code that calls new MyInt needs to delete the pointer to MyInt at some point in time.  I use the term "paired" loosely, but good programming patterns take into account that new/delete calls need to be "paired".

Comment: Learn the correct words: "Destructor" (noun) and "destroy" (verb) are the topic of your question.  *Deconstruct* or *deconstructor* is too easily confused with *destructure(r)* which splits apart the elements of a tuple or tuple-like object and has nothing to do with ending an object's lifetime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't understand why below MyInt deconstruct in main is never called and a memory leak happens.

Because you use an allocated pointer to `MyInt`.

You have to call

```
delete en;
```

to de-allocate it.

Deleting `en`, the destructor of `MyInt` is called and the memory associated to `_p` is de-allocated.

Suggestion: you tagged C++11, so you can use smart pointers.

So, inside `MyInt`, use a smart pointer

```
#include <memory>

class MyInt
{
    std::unique_ptr<int> my_p; 
public:
    MyInt (int *p = NULL) : my_p{p}
        { }

    // no explicit destructor required anymore

    int &operator*() { return *my_p; }
};
```

In `main()`, use a smart pointer as well:

```
#include <memory>

for (std::size_t i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
{
    std::unique_ptr<MyInt> en { new MyInt(new int(i)) };

    // use en and the content pointer

    // no more delete en required
}
```

Comment: If you are using C++14 or later, you should use `std::make_unique()` instead of `new` directly. More importantly, in C++11 and later, the `MyInt` constructor should take a `std::unique_ptr<int> p` instead of a raw `int* p`, and `std::move()` `p` into `my_p`

Answer (score 2):

Replace `MyInt* en` (a pointer to an object of type `MyInt` named `en`) with `MyInt en` (an object of type `MyInt` named `en`).

Or, explicitly call `delete` on your `MyInt*` pointer (albeit that would defeat the purpose of what you are trying to accomplish, I guess).

Comment: `MyInt` without `&` is not a reference.